# How to host a Website locally using iis to be accessed by other computers on same network?

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking, localhost, host

I have an asp.net website and i have hosted is locally using iis.

`http:localhost:3314`

I have a `TpLink router` with ip `192.168.0.101`. When i used `ipconfig` it show the ip address of the device `192.168.0.101` and the default gateway `192.168.0.1`.

This is my laptop and connected via wifi. Also the website is locally hosted on this laptop.

Then i connect my mobile via wifi it also show the ip adress `192.168.0.101` to the mobile.

My question is that how do i access my website from my mobile or other computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devices cannot have the same IP due to conflicts!

Maybe **DHCP is enabled** and you have to disable this option.Otherwise if the device has for example the ip  `192.168.1.56`  then the site will be accessible via **`http://192.168.1.56`** .if that doesn't work, there is a chance that there is a firewall running on your computer, or the httpd.conf is only listening on `127.0.0.1`

Comment: So that was the problem! Good

Comment: i forget to place ? at the end. By the way i have disable the DHCP and restart the router. now i run the ipconfig it still showing the ip address 192.168.0.101 ? what to do now

Comment: No problem the other divices will get 192.168.0.102 for example .So the first device has the 101 which means you can access your local site now.

Comment: i have tested but still its not connecting

Comment: Something else happens maybe firewall

Comment: ah just trying to figure out the route cause

Comment: i want to let you know i just allowed the port from the firewall and the website is running on other computers but one new problem i am facing now. the mobile devices are not connecting to wifi. so now what i do for them?

Comment: unfortunately i donnot find any option for mobile devices. My router is tpLink tl-wr740n

Comment: Let me check this out!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61787/discussion-between-csdtesting-and-hassaan-khan).